# Using CSS in Markdown file removes other styling

Tags: css, markdown

I want to add custom CSS in my Markdown (.md) file. I have looked here : http://www.mkdocs.org/ and found the extra_css, but I wish to have the CSS in the same file.

I have tried adding style tags at the top of the page like so :

```
<style> body { background:red } </style>
```

But it seems to remove all the other styling on the page.

Question is, how do I add my own CSS to my markdown file ?

Comment: can you show you .md flie or where you have tried the <style> body { background:red } </style>

Comment: Not sure of the easiest way to share the file, so I have just placed the text in this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fr7d8uqr/ that's all I have in my markdown file. Thanks @SahilDhir

Comment: ok so taking this example- you want to show your .md file with background red?

Comment: @SahilDhir That was just a test, what I want is some styling for the tables

Comment: Sharing the cheatsheet https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables

Comment: That's what I am already following, but no where does it say about styling the table @SahilDhir

Comment: CSS stands for "Cascading Style Sheets". You need to learn how the "cascading" part works, or how one rule takes precedence over another. There are plenty of questions and answers here which discuss that. I'd suggest doing a search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally the purpose of markdown file is **plain text formatting** syntax. Adding custom styles is actually counter productive of the format hence there is a good reason why styles were left alone for .md files. Having said that, there are workarounds for everything. Read on if your still interested.

I wouldn't personally recommend it but if you need to add custom styles then you could try the following:

- Increase the **specificity** of your styles for easier overriding.
- You could use [Marked](http://marked2app.com/help/Custom_Styles.html), a previewer for md files which gives you the ability to add custom styles.
- Use **inline styles**, inline styles have more priority than internal styles(the one you mentioned)

eg: `<body style="background: red;">...</body>`

- Using R Markdown, you can add your own CSS to an HTML document using the `css` option:

Reference: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#custom_css

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
---
```

Hope this helped

Comment: The R Markdown looks cool. However, I just want the most simplest way of getting my tables to look like the tables in this example : https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet . Adding CSS to my .md file, seems to remove the markdown CSS. What would you recommend ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy - Well, unfortunately there seems to be no efficient way to get what you asked for. The styling you see in the Markdown-Cheatsheet is coming from [github.css](https://gist.github.com/andyferra/2554919) and not through the .md file itself